# Spotify on Mac: Songs constantly won't play and get skipped over

Tags: spotify

An example:

My friend running the app right next to me is able to play the same songs without a problem from his phone, yet on my Mac app it just skips over them. I've been having this problem for lots of tracks for a long time. Has anyone else had this problem? Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by completely nuking the app and all support folders and re-installing.